# UINavigationController navigationBarHidden set to true only for a single view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

Assuming, I have a view hierarchy of type:

```
A [rootviewcontroller of a UINavigationController] --> B --> C
```

I want to disable the `navigationBar` for A but enable it for B & C.

1. Is it possible to do so?
2. Currently I am achieving this by enabling it in `viewWillAppear` for B & C but disabling when `viewWillAppear` for A. It kind of does the job but it feels unnatural and forced. Is there a right way of doing this?

Comment: I think this is the right way, though you shouldn't have to set it in C, if the navigation always goes from A to B to C.

Comment: You could also do it in viewDidLoad then in won't be done every time the view appears but only the first time.

Comment: Did you try to enable the navigation in `viewDidDisAppear` of vc A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better hide the navigationBar inside viewDidAppear method.

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{  

        [yourNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];   
   }
```